# Как получить список классов пространства имен?

Tags: c#, классы, namespace

Нашел такой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
...

private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
    {
        return
          assembly.GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                  .ToArray();
    }
```

И в методе Start:

```
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "System");
Debug.Log(typelist[0].Name);
```

Выдает ошибку, выход за границы массива.

Comment: скорее всего потому что typelist пустой. Чтобы понять почему - замени Where в функции на `Select(t => new {t.FullName, t.Namespace})` - чтобы видеть какие типы вообще есть и какие у них неймспейсы

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код ищет классы не во всех сборках, а только в одной.

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() - это текущая сборка.

Если в ней нет ни одного класса с нейспейсом System (а его там скорее всего нет, это же ваш код) - то массив на выходе будет пустым.

Попробуйте явно указать сборку System в вашем коде (или любую другую сборку, в которой точно есть такие классы), или поискать класс с тем неймспейсом, который есть в вашей сборке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не совсем понимаю, как _явно указать сборку System_. Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Ссылку на экземпляр сборки можно получить из любого типа, объявленного в ней: `typeof(Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider).Assembly`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: К сожалению, 'Microsoft.CSharp' недоступен в Unity.